# Have the scrollbars on Google Chrome Desktop decreased in size?

Tags: google-chrome

My Google Chrome on WIndows 7 has just been updated to the version 32 and the scrollbars look different.

The new width seems to be 15px. Was the scrollbars a bit wider in previous versions?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the scrollbars are indeed different in Chrome 32.

The scroll bars in Chrome 32 are Chrome OS style: flat, and without arrows at either end. They are also slightly narrower. I took a screenshot of an old one and a new one. The old one appears to be 16px wide while the new one is 15px wide.